# How to select a li in a ul with id modifier?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Trying to select the 'contacts' li within CSS and add a right margin.

```css
.navLinks #contacts {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navLinks">
 <li id="contacts"><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a></li>
 <li id="about"><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
 <li id="index"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have also tried to select it with `.navlinks li #contacts` and just `#contacts`. Neither seem to work; I'm not sure why.

Comment: `navlinks` should be `navLinks`

Comment: although correct, this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: what's the issue ??. If you are looking for `margin-right` then you need something in the right side

Comment: for some reason this won't select the element I want, therefore not allowing me to add a margin or anything else.

Comment: working for me https://jsfiddle.net/Ly36etzz/

Comment: Have you checked with `Inspect Element` to see if the style is getting applied or not? `Margin-right` wont have visible effects until you have a `background-color`

Comment: `.navLinks li #contacts` would definitely not work because it will look for a child of `li` to have an id of `#contacts`. Otherwise, I ran the code snippet and it seems to be working as you intended.

Comment: @sanatsathyan If you delete your answer you will regain any lost reputation. Downvotes on answers are to indicate that the answer is not useful or are incorrect; it's not a personal slight or anything :-)

Comment: yeah, im not sure why it's not working how i want. possibly an issue with other code, thanks for the help

Comment: @AndrewFalck If you try other properties, you will see the selector is working, and it's just a misunderstanding of how `li` elements work. See Friday's answer for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: You should add more details on what the look you are trying to achieve is because your selector is fine right now. If you add more code and explain what you want, we can provide you a better answer

Answer (score 2):

The `li` element is a block element with a full width of 100%; that means it stretched to the full width of the row. if you are to use margin on it, you need to either add width property to it, or you need to make the display property `inline`.

Try this; you will see the effect.

```css
.navLinks #contacts{
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  color: red;
  background: red;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navLinks">
  <li id="contacts"><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a></li>
  <li id="about"><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
  <li id="index"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Margin works on block elements without defining a width

Answer (score 2):

Margin-right doesn't seems to be right. Because anyway, you cannot see that because this is in the left side. And nothing wrong in referring the contact id from the navlinks. Perhaps you want it to move a bit to right right. For that use margin-left

```css
.navLinks #contacts {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navLinks">
  <li id="contacts"><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a></li>
  <li id="about"><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
  <li id="index"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
.navLinks #contacts {
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navLinks">
  <li id="contacts"><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a></li>
  <li id="about"><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
  <li id="index"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
</ul>
```